# Multiple independent instance of same component Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and trying to create a multi-window popup box in the application and using the same component for all windows and I am loading window using ComponentFactoryResolver.

I am able to load the multiple instances of a window without any problem as well as able to pass information to the new window including window header(User Name) information along with the message list and the user name stay unique as expected but however all the message are replacing with whatever is in the very last instance and replacing all message with  instance of last one.

> dynamic content loading code:

```
`loadSingleWindow(user_info)

 {
  const chatBoxFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(WindowComponent);
  const viewContainerRef  = this.container;
 // viewContainerRef.clear();

    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(chatBoxFactory);
   // this.chatService.joinChat(user_info);

  const windowInstance = <WindowComponent>(this.componentRef.instance);
  windowInstance.chatUser = user_info;
  this.chatService.loadExistingMessage('').subscribe(data => {
    windowInstance.messages = data;
  });

}
destroyComponent() {
  this.componentRef.destroy();
}
`
```

WindowComponent looks like below.

```
export class ChatWindowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public messages: Array<ChatMessage> = [];
  activeRoom: any;

  public chatUser;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log('hello world');
  }
}
```

> In the view of WindowComponents I am looping messages object to show
>   all message.

Image with two instances of the same component with a unique header but message part is replacing by whichever load in the last:

[image: Image with two instances of the same component with a unique header but message part is replacing by whichever load in the last]

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine the hanging `subscription` is the issue. Change your code to just get the value once by using the `take` operator:

```
this.chatService.loadExistingMessage('').pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(data => {
  windowInstance.messages = data;
});
```

Comment: It works well thank you.  But I run through another problem again whenever I am sending a message from one window it's receiving in all windows.

I tried to put that take logic in this but not sure how that take is working in this.

 constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
    this.chatService.onNewMessageReceived().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.messages.push(data);
    });
  }

Comment: @Koders you have to determine somehow from the message stream to which window it should be directed to. You can use the `filter()` pipe for this

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.